# Converter coluna de data frame de caracteres para numérico

Tags: r, data.frame

Ao tentar converter os valores de texto das colunas de um `data.frame`, criado utilizando `Stringasfactor = FALSE`, em numéricos, obtive um resultado anormal por coerção:

```
> str(ccredito$Restaurantes)
 chr [1:20] "49,74" "15,98" "59,4" "14" "57,42" "64,4" "15,4" "29,9" "28,22" "12" "63,25" ...
> colunanumerica <- as.numeric(ccredito$Restaurantes)
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> colunanumerica
[1] NA NA NA 14 NA NA NA NA NA 12 NA NA  6 NA NA NA NA 20 35 NA
```

Como corrigir e/ou evitar essa coerção incorreta?

Answer (score 5):

A conversão do `as.numeric` trata o `.` como separador de inteiros / decimais, e não o `,`. Uma solução simples é realizar a troca antes da chamada ao `as.numeric`:

```
colunanumerica <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", ccredito$Restaurantes))
```

Answer (score 3):

O R não entende `,` como separador de decimais, por isso você primeiro precisa substituí-las por pontos e depois transformar em numérico.

Isso pode ser feito assim:

```
s <- c("49,74", "15,98", "59,4")
library(stringr)
s <- str_replace_all(s, ",", ".")
as.numeric(s)
```

Geralmente isso pode ser corrigido logo na leitura dos dados, usando o argumento `dec = ","` na função `read.table`.